# R plot font issue

Tags: r, plot

Trying to plot a histogram in R 4.2.0, the fonts are not shown properly [image]

Searching online couldn't find anything useful. Any hint, what is missing?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /miniconda3/envs/plotter/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0
```

Comment: We would need to know a lot more about your system. Results of `sessionInfo()` and the output from a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: The code successfully runs in Rstudio inside windows environment but fails as above in linux environment when run as command line via Rscript. The error is not reproducible in different environment. The Linux R environment is new and I think some packages related to fonts are missing in Linux R but do not know what.

Comment: please add that information to your question. Can we have a [mcve]? Are you doing anything with non-standard fonts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load a non-standard font, you might check out the `font_add_google()` function in the [sysfonts package](https://rdrr.io/cran/sysfonts/man/font_add_google.html)

Answer (score 0):

Installing R-essentials using conda solved the problem. Just keeping this post with answer in case someone else might have the same problem.

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-essentials
```